# How to add weapon trail to sword swings?

Tags: 3d, opengl-es2, graphic-effects, combat, godot-3

I want to add the translucent blue swish following the sword when it is swung, but I don't even know what to call it, so I can't search it.

[image: Example of sword trail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing this in Godot 3:

- Animated: You can use `CSGPolygon`, keyframe the `polygon` property in an `AnimationPlayer` and make sure the track is set to continuous.
- Procedural: Create an `ImmediateGeometry`, have it follow to points (e.g. `Position3D`) which can be attached to the character via `BoneAttachment` or via `RemoteTransform`, and each frame it records the positions in an array, an outputs new geometry. See [Using ImmediateGeometry](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.6/tutorials/3d/procedural_geometry/immediategeometry.html).

*I had a look at the asset library, and the solution we can find there uses `ImmediateGeometry`.*

In either case you need to use a material that completes the effect with color and transparency.

---

Note for Godot 4 users: `ImmediateGeometry` was removed in favor or `ImmediateMesh`. So instead of a `ImmediateGeometry` node, you have a `MeshInstance3D` node with its `mesh` set to a `ImmediateMesh`.